# Number of Likes increases when page is refreshed

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i want to update the number of likes increased when the user clicks on the like button. like on my site , when on this page
http://modelspk.com/urwa-tul-wusqa-model18
user clicks on the like button, the no of likes in increased by one in the database. but until the page is not refreshed, it is not updated at the front end. the code currently i am using is as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#likeThis").live("click", function () {
        var pid = document.getElementById("pid");
        var uRL = "/updateRatings.aspx?opt=1&pid=" + pid.value;
        $.post(uRL);
        alert('You Like This');
        this.disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("dislikeThis").disabled = true;
        return false;
    });

    $("#dislikeThis").live("click", function () {
        var pid = document.getElementById("pid");
        var uRL = "/updateRatings.aspx?opt=2&pid=" + pid.value;
        $.post(uRL);
        alert("You don't Like This");
        this.disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("likeThis").disabled = true;
        return false;
    });         

</script>
```

and the html input button for like or dislike are as follows..

```
 <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="newPhotoID" runat="server" />
                        <input type="hidden" id="pid" value="<%=ModelID%>" />
                        <asp:Label ID="lblModelID" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                        <table width="253" align="center">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left" class="txt" style="color: #0068c6; font-weight: bold;">
                                    Rate This:
                                </td>
                                <td align="center" class="WaterText">
                                    <input type="image" id="likeThis" onclick="javascript:rateThis(1,<%=ModelID%>);"
                                        src="/images2/inact-thumb.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='/images2/active-thumb.jpg'"
                                        onmouseout="this.src='/images2/inact-thumb.jpg'" />&nbsp;<%=Likes%>
                                    <span class="txt" style="color: #0068c6; font-weight: bold;">Likes</span>
                                </td>
                                <td align="center" class="WaterText">
                                    <input type="image" id="dislikeThis" src="/images2/no-inact.jpg" onclick="javascript:rateThis(2,<%=ModelID%>)"
                                        onmouseover="this.src='/images2/no-active.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='/images2/no-inact.jpg'" />&nbsp;<%=Dislikes%>
                                    <span class="txt" style="color: #0068c6; font-weight: bold;">Disikes</span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td width="127" align="right" class="WaterText">
                        <%=Views %>
                        <span class="txt" style="color: #0068c6; font-weight: bold;">Views</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

what i want to do is that as the user clicks on the like button, it should be increased by one at the same time without refreshing the page.

Regards:
Mudassir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should manually update the no. of likes and dislikes by using Javascript or jQuery.

```
//added new argument, pass image for further use
<input type="image" id="likeThis" onclick="javascript:rateThis(1,<%=ModelID%>,this);"
```

src="/images2/inact-thumb.jpg" ;<%=Likes%>

```
//do not use live.. use simple javascript

function rateThis(1,modelId,image){
    $.ajax({
        url:"/updateRatings.aspx?opt=1&pid=" + pid.value,
        success:function(result){
            $(image).siblings("span").text(result.d);//update the no of likes and dislikes
        }
    })
}
```

[asp.net return data in Page_Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659767/asp-net-return-data-in-page-load)

You should refer above link for how to get json data from page as you are using a page not a web service.

Answer (score 0):

Since .**live**() is **deprecated** try to use .**on**() like

```
$("#likeThis").on("click", function () {
```

and put these functions in document.ready like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#likeThis").on("click", function () {
     ---------------------
});
```

Comment: my current code is working fine but the only issue is that the total number is not increased by 1 until the page is refreshed.. what i want to do is that as the user clicks on the like button, the total number of likes on the page should be updated without refreshing the page...