# What I missed in my AJAX Code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

When user select any value from drop down, then Ajax has to call server and return some values through JSON object.

Here is my **Ajax code**

```
//AJAX Security
$('#ddlSecurityLevel').change(function () {
    if ($('#ddlSecurityLevel').val() !== 'None') {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'AjaxSecurity.aspx?securityLevelOrUser=SecurityLevel&SecurityKey=1&ReportName=TotalSales',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: 'json',
            //dataType: JSON.stringify(Data),
            cache: false,
            success: AjaxSucceeded,
            error: AjaxFailed
        });
        function AjaxSucceeded(result) {
            //alert("hello");
            alert(result.d);    // output UNDEFINED
        }
        function AjaxFailed(result) {
            alert("Error");
            alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
        }
    }
});
```

**Asp.net C# code**

```
public class GetResult
{
    public string removedReportName { get; set; }
    public string removedColumnNames { get; set; }
    public string removedFilterNames { get; set; }
}

public partial class AjaxSecurity : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        string securityLevelOrUser = Request["securityLevelOrUser"].ToString();

        if (securityLevelOrUser.Equals("SecurityLevel"))
        {
            string jsonString = js.Serialize(getResultBySecurityLevel(Request["SecurityKey"], Request["ReportName"]));
            Response.Write(jsonString);
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

    private GetResult getResultBySecurityLevel(string securityLevel,string reportName)
    {
        GetResult getResult = new GetResult();

        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HQWebMatajer13"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ReportHide,RColumnName,RFilterName FROM SecurityLevelDetails WHERE SecurityLevel=@SecurityLevel and ReportName=@ReportName";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReportName", reportName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SecurityLevel", securityLevel);

            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rd=cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while(rd.Read())
            {
                getResult.removedReportName = rd["ReportHide"].ToString();
                getResult.removedColumnNames = rd["RColumnName"].ToString();
                getResult.removedFilterNames = rd["RFilterName"].ToString();
            }

        }

        return getResult;
    }

}
```

When I run my Asp.net code with following parameter, It returns values in browser

**URL**
`http://localhost:55047/AjaxSecurity.aspx?securityLevelOrUser=SecurityLevel&SecurityKey=4&ReportName=TotalSales`

**Response.Write**
`{"removedReportName":"1","removedColumnNames":"ItemLookupCode,Department","removedFilterNames":"ExtendedDescription,DepartmentName"}`

But the output alert is **Undefined**

Comment: In your ajax URL, the query string parameter is securityLevelOrUser, SecurityKey and ReportName. But in your getResultBySecurityLevel() method, you have only 2 parameters. And this parameter name should be same with the querystring name. Please check once

Comment: @BasantaMatia please check my page load method

Comment: Remove d from alert(result.d);

Comment: I'm not into ASP.net but is this correct `data: 'json',` ? isn't suppose to be `datatype` then `data be the form inputs?

Comment: No No...Comment that one too. In data: You need to pass data to server method.

Comment: Yes, It should be datatype:'json'. Please see my answer bellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment data:'json' and Remove d from alert(result.d);

To access the data in js alert you can write like this,

```
function AjaxSucceeded(result) {
    if(result!=null)
     {
      alert(result[0].removedReportName +"," result[0].removedColumnNames);
     }
 }
```

In your Page_Load method, you need to clear out the output and write your own,

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
Response.Write(jsonString);
Response.End();
```

Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659767/asp-net-return-data-in-page-load) link, this is what you need

Comment: still undefined

Comment: Please write like this and check once alert(result.removedReportName)

Comment: Do I need to remove `data:'json'`?.

Comment: Yah! I already mentioned in my answer u need to comment that line or remove that.

Comment: I removed that `data:json`, still the output same. What about `datatype:'json'`?... do i need to add or remove?

Comment: Bro! U can remove that one too. It's working fine in my side. So u need to check once properly.

Comment: I remove both. Still no response

Comment: Did you check with this, alert(result.removedReportName);

Comment: Yes ofcourse. I tried `result[0].removedReportName / result.removedReportName / result.d`. still undefined.

Comment: See my updated answer above. U need to add Clear() method. Let me know whether its working or not.

Comment: If i `alert (result)` it returns all the values. There is no need to change in page load function

Comment: Ok Great. Then u can show any value u want in ur alert box just by writing like alert(result.YOUR_PARAMETER_NAME_HERE);

Comment: I got it.Thanks. Can you tell me why Web Method is also used for ajax. Then what is the difference?

Comment: See, using ajax you can call a method asynchronously. That means, without loading the whole page to the server, u can send a request to server and get/post the data silently. Please go through this to know about Ajax   https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-ASPNet-Page-Method-using-jQuery-AJAX-Example.aspx